# How to force package-utils-upgrade-all to completely replace packages when upgrading?

Tags: package

`lsp-mode` doesn't support upgrading the package, instead, a full re-install is required each time ([see report](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2552#issuecomment-764964290)).

(In my case, deleting the directory and re-installing works, upgrading doesn't).

Is there a way to force `package-utils-upgrade-all` to perform the equivalent of a fresh-install when upgrading a package to a new version?

Comment: A hunch: did you try `async-bytecomp-package-mode`?

Comment: No, I never heard of this. While it's possible it's getting called indirectly - `async-bytecomp-allowed-packages` is `nil` on my system.

Comment: I meant you should try using it, at least for the package that's giving you trouble. `async-bytecomp-package-mode` will byte-compile the package in a separate clean environment, where the previous version of the package is not loaded.